# Is there any way to remove paired ble device programmatically in windows?

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

[Sorry it's in Chinese, but the button's text is "Remove Device"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T3WD.png)

I've already tried several methods I found

1. Bluetooth Command line tools: With this tool I can remove BT devices but seems not working for BLE devices.
2. Devcon & pnputil: I have also tried using devcon & pnputil through PowerShell to remove ble devices. I'm not pretty sure if I was wrong with the procedure, but when I successfully removed the BLE device and the device doesn't appear in both Device Manager and setting. Then I use command to scan devices or reboot my computer, it shows up again. So I checked the registry then realize even it's removed successfully, it still shows in registry.
3. Delete in registry: Although it can remove devices just as I want, it works after reboot makes it inconvenient to me.

My project is about testing ble devices, I have to connect device, test it then disconnect also remove it from paired device.
So I wonder is there any other way that I can do the same thing the button "Remove Device" in setting does with C#, cmd or PowerShell. Or is there anything wrong with what I've tried, please let me know. Thanks

Comment: 1. You do not need to pair with BLE device on Win 10 before connect. It is required for Win 8.1 only. 2. DeviceInformationPairing.UnpairAsync()

Comment: @MikePetrichenko Well...this problem has bothered me for quite a long time since I don't know much in this area. I think I'm in wrong direction the whole time, I seached how to remove device instead of unpair it. The UnpairAsync() works just fine. Really appreciate for your help.

Comment: @johnson711 If this worked you can also answer you own question and thereby help other people find the answer.